# C++ Strange Text From SQLIte

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to create a constructor that will populate data from a sqlite database.
Everything appears to be working accept when I run the for loop that creates the objects and populates my table I get some strange output. I think it may have something to do with memory pointers, but I am very new to C++ and I am not sure what I did wrong.

Inventory Constructor

```
Inventory::Inventory(int id)
{
CC_Number cn;
char result[100];   // array to hold the result.
strcpy(result,"SELECT * FROM Inventory Where Inventory_ID = ");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(id));
strcat(result,";");
db = new CC_Database("CC_Prepper_Inventory.sqlite");

vector<vector<string> > r = db->query(result);
db->close();
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = r.begin(); it < r.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<string> row = *it;
    CC_String cs;
        setInv_ID(atoi(cs.toConChar(row.at(0))));
        Item item(atoi(cs.toConChar(row.at(1))));
        setItem(item);
        setQnty(atof(cs.toConChar(row.at(2))));
        Location loc(atoi(cs.toConChar(row.at(3))));
        setLoc(loc);
}

}
```

Item Constructor

```
Item::Item(int id)
{
CC_Number cn;
char result[100];   // array to hold the result.
strcpy(result,"SELECT * FROM Item Where Item_ID = ");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(id));
strcat(result,";");
db = new CC_Database("CC_Prepper_Inventory.sqlite");

vector<vector<string> > r = db->query(result);
db->close();
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = r.begin(); it < r.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<string> row = *it;
    CC_String cs;
        setItem_ID(atoi(cs.toConChar(row.at(0))));

        setCat_ID(atoi(cs.toConChar(row.at(1))));
        setItem_Name(cs.toConChar(row.at(2)));
}

}
```

Location Constructor

```
Location::Location(int id)
{
CC_Number cn;
char result[100];   // array to hold the result.
strcpy(result,"SELECT Loc_ID, Loc_Name FROM Location Where Loc_ID = ");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(id));
strcat(result,";");
db = new CC_Database("CC_Prepper_Inventory.sqlite");

vector<vector<string> > r = db->query(result);
db->close();
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = r.begin(); it < r.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<string> row = *it;
    CC_String cs;
        setLoc_ID(id);
        setLoc_Name(cs.toConChar(row.at(1)));
}
}
```

Category Constructor

```
Category::Category(int id)
{
CC_Number cn;
char result[100];   // array to hold the result.
strcpy(result,"SELECT * FROM Category Where Cat_ID = ");
strcat(result,cn.int_to_char(id));
strcat(result,";");
db = new CC_Database("CC_Prepper_Inventory.sqlite");

vector<vector<string> > r = db->query(result);
db->close();
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = r.begin(); it < r.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<string> row = *it;
    CC_String cs;
        setCat_ID(id);
        setCat_Name(cs.toConChar(row.at(1)));
}
}
```

For Loop Used to Call Constructors

```
void MainWindow::fillTable()
{
ui->mainTable->clear();
db = new CC_Database("CC_Prepper_Inventory.sqlite");
vector<vector<string> > result = db->query("SELECT Inventory_ID FROM Inventory;");
db->close();
ui->mainTable->setRowCount(result.size());
int j = 0;
for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = result.begin(); it < result.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<string> row = *it;
    Inventory i(atoi(cs.toConChar(row.at(0))));

    cout << i.getItem().getItem_Name() << endl;
    cout << i.getItem().getCategory().getCatName() << endl;
    cout << cn.dbl_to_char(i.getQnty()) << endl;
    cout << i.getLoc().getLocName() << endl;

    QTableWidgetItem *newItem1 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getItem().getItem_Name()));
    QTableWidgetItem *newItem2 = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getItem().getCategory().getCatName()));
    QTableWidgetItem *newItem3 = new     QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(cn.dbl_to_char(i.getQnty())));
    QTableWidgetItem *newItem4 = new     QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(i.getLoc().getLocName()));
    ui->mainTable->setItem(j,1,newItem1);
    ui->mainTable->setItem(j,2,newItem2);
    ui->mainTable->setItem(j,3,newItem3);
    ui->mainTable->setItem(j,4,newItem4);
    i.clear();
    j++;
}

QStringList qsl;
qsl << "Item" << "Category" << "Quantity" << "Location";
ui->mainTable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(qsl);
}
```

Here is the output when I Cout the results.

```
Food
1
B.O.L.

Food
3
B.O.L.

Food
4

0�an error
Food
3.14
LE Item (
Item_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Cat_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
Item_Name TEXT NOT NULL)P++Ytablesqlite_sequencesqlite_sequenceCREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)� ��

Food
5
```

I know this is information overload, but I don't know how else to explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is not in the lines you have posted, but elsewhere. However your code urges some modifications:

1. don't use characters array to hold SQL queries, use std::string
2. don't open the connection to the database for every single query... open it once and perform multiple queries

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the FillTable function as everything prints out fine until I use i.getItem().getItem_Name() and i.getLoc().getLocName() All the other functions seem to work ok. Could it be because these variables are const char*

Comment: That was it I changed them to strings and it works now. I had made them const char* because I was constantly having to convert strings and it seemed to save a step. Now I know better.
Thanks,